# Can we put query directly in AWS Athena URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am working on a project and it has web interfaces that will list out things like Tables and has hyperlink to Athena, so that users can view data and run queries.

The hyperlink looks like below:

https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/athena/home

I have also noticed that I can go to previous query by extending the URL's as below:

https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/athena/home?region=us-east-1#/query-editor/history/xxebdc9c-1xx3-4xx3-931a-27c8xxxxxxxx

Is there any way that we can add specific query to the URL like below?

[https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/athena/home?region='us-east-1#&query=select%20*%20from%20catalog.table%20limit%2010](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/athena/home?region=%27us-east-1#&query=select%20*%20from%20catalog.table%20limit%2010)

Comment: No, you can't. But even if you could, it would be a security risk.

Comment: Why? Use the Athena SDK provided by AWS.